# How to compare a variable against two values at the same time?

Tags: java

I need to improve this statement by either correcting it or making it shorter

```
if (0 <= age <= 100) // age is between 0 and 100)
```

I am totally confused about spending 20 minutes on the question. It seems really simple but the only revision I could think of is

```
if (0 <= age && age <= 100)
```

and that doesn't seem right. Am I just missing something obvious? Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: imo it'd read better if you wrote `age >= 0 && age <= 100` , but that might just be subjective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your revision is correct. `if (0 <= age && age <= 100)` is the correct way to do it. There really isn't a simpler way.

Comment: FWIW the original would be valid in Python or CoffeeScript.